# Force close issue

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a program that take upto 6 integers and then convert it to words, unfortunately I can't see whether I'm doing right or wrong because when I try to run. It force closes.

Here is my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

    final EditText numbers =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String numberz =numbers.getText().toString();
    final long number = Long.parseLong(numberz);

    Button btnConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     
    btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String returnz = Words.convert(number); 

                       }  });


        }}
```

and here is the class I should be calling when I click the button Words.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Words extends ActionBarActivity {

final EditText result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


      private static final String[] tensNames = {
        "",
        " ten",
        " twenty",
        " thirty",
        " forty",
        " fifty",
        " sixty",
        " seventy",
        " eighty",
        " ninety"
      };

      private static final String[] numNames = {
        "",
        " one",
        " two",
        " three",
        " four",
        " five",
        " six",
        " seven",
        " eight",
        " nine",
        " ten",
        " eleven",
        " twelve",
        " thirteen",
        " fourteen",
        " fifteen",
        " sixteen",
        " seventeen",
        " eighteen",
        " nineteen"
      };

      private Words() {}

      private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(int number) {
        String soFar;

        if (number % 100 < 20){
          soFar = numNames[number % 100];
          number /= 100;
        }
        else {
          soFar = numNames[number % 10];
          number /= 10;

          soFar = tensNames[number % 10] + soFar;
          number /= 10;
        }
        if (number == 0) return soFar;
        return numNames[number] + " hundred" + soFar;
      }


      public static String convert(long number) {
        // 0 to 999 999 999 999
        if (number == 0) { return "zero"; }

        String snumber = Long.toString(number);

        // pad with "0"
        String mask = "000000000000";
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(mask);
        snumber = df.format(number);

        // XXXnnnnnnnnn
        int billions = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(0,3));
        // nnnXXXnnnnnn
        int millions  = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(3,6));
        // nnnnnnXXXnnn
        int hundredThousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(6,9));
        // nnnnnnnnnXXX
        int thousands = Integer.parseInt(snumber.substring(9,12));

        String tradBillions;
        switch (billions) {
        case 0:
          tradBillions = "";
          break;
        case 1 :
          tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
          + " billion ";
          break;
        default :
          tradBillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(billions)
          + " billion ";
        }
        String result =  tradBillions;

        String tradMillions;
        switch (millions) {
        case 0:
          tradMillions = "";
          break;
        case 1 :
          tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
             + " million ";
          break;
        default :
          tradMillions = convertLessThanOneThousand(millions)
             + " million ";
        }
        result =  result + tradMillions;

        String tradHundredThousands;
        switch (hundredThousands) {
        case 0:
          tradHundredThousands = "";
          break;
        case 1 :
          tradHundredThousands = "one thousand ";
          break;
        default :
          tradHundredThousands = convertLessThanOneThousand(hundredThousands)
             + " thousand ";
        }
        result =  result + tradHundredThousands;

        String tradThousand;
        tradThousand = convertLessThanOneThousand(thousands);
        result =  result + tradThousand;

        // remove extra spaces!
        return result.replaceAll("^\\s+", "").replaceAll("\\b\\s{2,}\\b", " ");}



      public void main(String[] args) {
        result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(0));
        result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(1));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(16));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(100));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(118));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(200));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(219));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(800));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(801));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(1316));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(1000000));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(2000000));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(3000200));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(700000));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(9000000));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(9001000));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(123456789));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(2147483647));
      result.setText("*** " + Words.convert(3000000010L));

      }}
```

my logcat here:

```
04-22 02:18:05.144: D/dalvikvm(1066): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 6% free 3078K/3256K, paused 30ms, total 32ms
04-22 02:18:05.334: D/gralloc_goldfish(1066): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-22 02:18:09.134: I/Choreographer(1066): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 02:18:21.704: I/Choreographer(1066): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 02:51:00.024: I/Choreographer(1066): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 03:00:00.054: I/Choreographer(1066): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 03:00:01.084: I/Choreographer(1066): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 03:27:10.474: I/Choreographer(1066): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-22 03:29:35.064: D/AndroidRuntime(1122): Shutting down VM
04-22 03:29:35.064: W/dalvikvm(1122): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2abfba8)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): Process: com.example.torres, PID: 1122
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.torres/com.example.torres.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.example.torres.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-22 03:29:35.094: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     ... 11 more
04-22 03:29:35.134: D/dalvikvm(1122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 100K, 6% free 3087K/3256K, paused 39ms, total 43ms
```

Comment: also post your logcat.

Comment: always mention your logcat logs in these cases.

Comment: @Taba why do you have main method in Words? Where is it called. This `final EditText result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);` in Words is wrong and get text from edittext in `onClick`

Comment: `public static String convert(long number) {}` get invalid `long`.

Comment: I think there are too many closing brackets in your MainActivity onCreate. And check this: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""` - You are **trying to convert an empty string to a long** (!!).

Comment: @Taba You extend `ActionBarActivity` in Words but i don't see `onCreate`. No layout set to the Activity and you iniitlaize `EditText`. It is probably meant to be a utility class. Its better you start with a tutorial

Comment: @Raghunandan : sir its the textview where the result should be posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your numberz variable is null on application start. Try this....

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

  final EditText numbers =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

  Button btnConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);     
  btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       String numberz =numbers.getText().toString();
       try {
           final long number = Long.parseLong(numberz);
           String returnz = Words.convert(number); 
       } catch ( NumberFormatException e) {
           //Toast.makeToast("illegal number or empty number" , toast.long)
       }


    } 
     });
    }
  }
```

Comment: there is no nullpointerexception. `""` is a empty string not a valind long value. Hence `NumberFOrmatException`. `numberz` is not null

Comment: Sir thanks! it now doesn't force close :) but when I click my button nothing happens >.<

Comment: try Sysout on the returnz and see whether your return is correct... if it is, you can either display it on the screen or use it where ever you see fit. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
String numberz =numbers.getText().toString();
```

will return `numberz="";` and on `convert(`) method in `Words` class will resultant as `NumberFormatException : Invalid Long`. So you have to write below codes in `onClickListener()` of button.

```
btnConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       String numberz =numbers.getText().toString();
       try {
           final long number = Long.parseLong(numberz);
           String returnz = Words.convert(number); 
       } catch ( NumberFormatException e) {
           //Toast.makeToast("illegal number or empty number" , toast.long)
       }
    } 
     });
```